# Report's stretch table

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a problem with *JasperReports*'s report layouting.

The table can be 1-5 rows and it must stretch. If i set up height of the table more than actually data then table shrink but elements below the table doesn't change Y position. But if i set the table height too small so i get "Infinite loop" error. I tried different combinations of properties "Position Type", "Stretch Type", "Print when overflow", etc.

Help please! I saw examples with stretch TextFields, but if i use it i get Infinite loop error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem is fixed. I just put the table into subreport.

Answer (score 0):

To stretch a table,

1. Double click it in the 'Main Report'. This will open the table in a
   new tab. 
   [image]
2. In the tab 'Table', the hierarchy is defined in the
   'Outline'.
   [image]
3. Select the table and you can see the dimensions of the
   table in the advanced properties
   [image]

Alternatively, you can drag the table border with mouse to stretch it.

Comment: You didn't understand me :) I know how to stretch it manually. But i need a dynamic height. The table can be 1-5 rows and it must stretch. If i set up height of the table more than actually data then table shrink but elements below the table doesn't change Y position.